# setDrawable with dynamic parameter

Tags: android, listview, drawable

I am using a listview with a basic adapter.

- Each row has 1 imageview + 1 textview.
- I want to be able to populate the image of each row dynamically with code, not xml
- My images are located in my drawable folder.
- Each image already has a name: i1, i2, ..., i1000.
- When I populate my list, I want to be able to set i1 to row 1, i2 to row 2, i3 to row 3 etc.

The XML code for each row is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/containerView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imgView"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_width="50dip">        
</ImageView>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/descView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am using an adapter to populate the relevant data in each row. Let's take the example to populate the text, it works well:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.descView);
tv.setText(<some dynamic data with whatever parameters and conditions>);
```

But when I want to do the same thing to populate dynamically the image, I am stuck:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)ll.findViewById(R.id.imgView);           
iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.<problem is here since it has to be a static name of a file, not dynamic>)
```

Of course I could use a big switch like this

```
switch (<some dynamic parameter>) {
case 1: iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.i1); break;
case 2: iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.i2); break;
case 3: iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.i3); break;
```

But that looks like a horrible choice, especially for long lists with thousands of images.

So how can I set images dynamically in this case without depending on a long and painful block of if else or a huge switch?

I hope this is clear, if no, please let me know I will do my best to clarify

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
{
int drawableid= this.getResources().getIdentifier("i"+i, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
iv.setBackgroundResource(drawableid);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Pragnani, I am not familiar with this. Will it set the background or do I need to set it after your code?

Comment: @Kintaro check my edit, you can directly set it as image Resource, As I did in the example

Comment: Thanks man, that does it. I just added the following to make it work: for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
{
int drawableid= this.getResources().getIdentifier("i"+String.valueOf(i), "drawable", this.getPackageName());
iv.setBackgroundResource(drawableid);

}

Answer (score 0):

in `Context getResources().getIdentifier("i1", "drawable", "your.package.name");`